# Application could not be uploaded on device

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a crossplatform solution for an application. I have recently tried to add push notifications functionality for my IOS project.

But when i try to install my project on my ios i get this error.

```
Package Inspection Failed Error (error: 0xe8000051).
```

I have tried:
 - Cleaning solution
 - rebuild
 - checking build action for my info.plist
 - removing bin folder

the full trace of the install looks like this:

```
PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30%
PackageInspectionFailed: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xhvJhV/extracted/ODEON.iOS.app/Frameworks/PersonalizedAdConsent.framework
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/anderslarsen/Documents/Projects/ODEON/ODEON/ODEON.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/ODEON.iOS.app' on the device 'Anders - iPhone': Package Inspection Failed Error (error: 0xe8000051).
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any Nuget Package?

Comment: yes:

Xamarin.Firebase.iOs.CloudMessaging
CarouselView.FormsPlugin
DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView
Xamarin.FFImageLoading.svg + .Forms + Transformations
NewtonSoft.Json

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct provisioning profile and that your info.plist is in development and not production mode?

Comment: is it aps-enviroment? it is in development

Comment: I need a solution for this, I started to get this issue yesterday, and cant fix this, deleting .bin and .obj folders do not help.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find the reason this happens and I researched a lot, 2 years after this question was done I'm still getting this error. From my personal experience, manually deleting "bin" and "obj" and then building the iOS project again would solve the issue.